# How to only show elements of a class that I clicked while hiding everything else with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, class

Beginner here, tried my best to look around but didn't find anything exactly the same.

I have a situation where I have multiple appearances of the same 4 types of links (each with their own class).

Ex:

```
<a href="#" class="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="link4">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" class="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="link4">Link 4</a>
```

I am trying to get it so if I click 'Link 1', any links with classes 2-4 disappear (off the page) and only links with the class, "link1" will show.

```
<a href="#" class="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link1">Link 1</a>`
```

I have tried creating assigning the clicked link to a variable and then using .not() or .siblings(), but so far can't get anything to work.

```
var clickedLink = $(this).closest('a').attr('class');
$(clickedLink).siblings().hide();
```

Also tried giving all of the links a shared class (such as class="test, link1") to .hide() and then .show(), but that would only hide() and would not show().

Thanks a ton for any help at all.

Comment: let's see your best attempt with `.not() or .siblings()`

Answer (score 1):

The following, simplified, example should help you on the way:

https://jsfiddle.net/jhqbf4nb/

```
$('.wrap a').click(function() {
  var $target = $(this);

  $target.siblings().not('.' + $target.attr('class')).hide();
})
```

Note I added a wrapper `.wrap` around the links to make selection a bit easier.

---

In fact, the above solution is a bit too simple to my liking. It should work in your case, but it does make a lot of assumptions about the DOM structure. In real life I would probably go for something in this order:

https://jsfiddle.net/jhqbf4nb/1/

```
var $links = $('.link');

$links.click(function() {
  var $target = $(this);
  var type = $target.data('type');

  $links.not('[data-type="' + type + '"]').hide();
})
```

I moved the 'type' to a `data-type` attribute. This way you can have as many classes as you like on those links. Also, they do not have to be siblings anymore, they can be anywhere in your DOM. This should be a lot more flexible, and keep up much better when the DOM changes in the future (and I believe it is easier to understand when you first read it as well, and I'm a big fan of self explaining code).

Answer (score 0):

Create a second class named "hidecontrol" (or "test" if you like) and when you'll click nomeone, hide evething:

`$(".hidecontrol").css("display","none");`

And show your element.

`<what_you_clicked>.css("display","block");`

Comment: if those people are within a div, be sure to keep the div's height or strange things will happen.

Comment: 1. # refers to an ID, so use .hidecontrol instead in your JS. 2. use build in jQUERY show and hide instead of css.

Comment: My mistake. Replace the "#" symbol by a dot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using this:

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  var className = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
  var $siblings = $(this).siblings(':not('.' + $(this).attr('class') + ')');
  $siblings.hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses toggle() function:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var check = $(this).attr('class');
    $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).attr('class') == check);
    });
});
```

See at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xekero/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

First, add an extra class that will cover all links and a data attribute that defines what links you want to show by clicking this link like so:

```
<a href="#" class="link link1" data-show-only="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link link2" data-show-only="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link link3" data-show-only="link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="link link4" data-show-only="link4">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" class="link link1" data-show-only="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link link2" data-show-only="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link link3" data-show-only="link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="link link4" data-show-only="link4">Link 4</a>
```

Then, use this JS on click.

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    $('.link').hide();
    var linksToShow = $(this).data('show-only');
    $('.' + linksToShow).show();
});
```

Working example for you :)
https://jsfiddle.net/oebgbue9/1/

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution, although it can probably be simplified with better jQuery selectors.

https://jsfiddle.net/tkcohpqv/1/

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this);

    //hide other links
    $('a').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass(clicked.attr('class'))) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```